# Sendmail configuration with user mapping on Solaris

Tags: configuration, solaris, sendmail, smtp

I have the following:

- `host1.intra.net` which has sendmail and users: `user1`, `user2` & `user3`. It is running SunOS 5.10.
- `host2.intra.net` which has SMTP server. No authentication, no encryption.
- Email addresses john.user1@company.com, ada.user2@company.com, alice.user3@company.com
- mailx 5.0 on host1.intra.net is being used to send emails

How could I:

- Configure sendmail on `host1.intra.net` to use SMTP on `host2.intra.net` with no authentication, no encryption.
- If an email is sent from the shell of `user1`, it should appear as being sent from `john.user1@company.com`.
- If an email is sent from the shell of user2, it should appear as being sent from `ada.user2@company.com`.
- If an email is sent from the shell of user3, it should appear as being sent from `alice.user3@company.com`.

Comment: You can do this using Sendmail.  You must populate the User Database with the appropriate records.  See Section 5.12 of http://http://www.sendmail.com/pdfs/open_source/installation_and_op_guide.pdf to get started.